# can not write in arabic inside an html header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I downloaded a CSS template and I am trying to translate it to Arabic. I'm using UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

When I write in Arabic outside the header, it is fine but when I put it inside it, I get only the English text but the Arabic disappear.

```
<div class="slogan">
    <h2> شركة  
          Company </h2> 
</div>
```

I think it has something to do with the CSS class but I only know [html](/questions/tagged/html) and don't know anything about [css](/questions/tagged/css).

The CSS class is:

```
.slogan {height:120px; overflow:hidden; text-align:center;}
.slogan h2 {margin:0; font-size:305%; line-height:1.1;}
```

Is there any thing I can do to the CSS file to help solve the problem?

Comment: It looks fine in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JAuA/). Maybe it has something to do with your other CSS styles...

Comment: Are there any other references to h2 in your CSS? My guess is that one of them changes the font, and that font doesn't support non-latin chars.

Comment: @A'rafAwady Can you make a fiddle where the Arabic text shows up outside the `h2`, but not inside it? Also, which browsers, which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

1-open start

2-open notepad

3-write your code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="slogan">
    <h2> شركة  
          Company </h2> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

4-when you saving file make Encoding: utf-8

5-file name name.html name.php